# Speed up big sql query with php loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to make these SQL querys faster. I've tried with indexes and so on but I'm abit unsure how to make it faster. Any tips or points are welcome. Its abit old code that an old programmer made, trying to fix it up. It's a MySQL database.

I have two tabels:

wp_l (550 000rows and growing each day) and wp_lP (540 000rows and growing)

Structure:

```
wp_l:
id - int(9)
epost - (varchar255)
userID - int(9)
date - timestamp
and a few more fields containing info thats not used in this case.

wp_lP:
id - int(9)
lID - int(9) [is the id it belongs to in wp_l, nothing is done in "mysql" to make them relate]
pID - int(9)
quantity - int(9)
```

My php code:

```
<?php
    $years = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT YEAR(date) AS year FROM wp_l WHERE userID = %d OR epost = %s GROUP BY year DESC", $current_user->ID, $current_user->user_email));
    if(count($years) == 0) {
        //No result
    } else {
    foreach ( $years as $year ) {

    echo $year->year;

        $myOrders2 = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_l WHERE YEAR(date) = %s AND (userID = %d OR epost = %s) ORDER by id DESC", $year->year, $current_user->ID, $current_user->user_email), ARRAY_N);
        for($i=0; $i<count($myOrders2); $i++) {

        $ar = substr($myOrders2[$i][3], 0, 4);

            $ordersProducts2[$i] = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_lP WHERE lID = %d ORDER by id", $myOrders2[$i][0]), ARRAY_N);

            for($j=0; $j<count($ordersProducts2[$i]); $j++) {
                $loopProductID = $ordersProducts2[$i][$j][2];
                $quantity = $ordersProducts2[$i][$j][3];
                $tid = $myOrders2[$i][3];
                include(locate_template('loopfile.php'));
            } 
        } 
    }
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use joins to  have only one SQL statement

Comment: So which fields are indexed?  Why do you assume that it can be faster?

Comment: Is there a common field? How do the two tables relate to one another?

Comment: Currently there are just a standard index on id on both tables. I assume it can be faster since its not uncommon that it takes around 30-40 seconds for some people to load it. 

Yeah I might try out to use joins to see if it works bettter.

Comment: wp_lP contains "products", the common field is lID that is related to wp_l's id.

Comment: So on `wp_l` both `epost` and `userID` should probably be indexed.  On `wp_lP` at least `lID` should be indexed.  Also, although it shouldn't be necessary, you could create a dateYear column and index that column, and then use that in your `WHERE` clause instead of `YEAR(date)` which will not take advantage of an index.